# custom sidebar plugin issue

Tags: plugins

We are currently using the wpmudev custom sidebar plugin on our website https://www.bodycote.com/

The plugin has been working fine for the last 2 years we run it with WPML and a number of other plugins and have had no issues at all.

However recently when we upgraded the wordpress core to 5.23 we have been unable to edit/amend any of the custom widgets that we had set up on the website.

All of the current sidebars still appear on the front end of the website and work in the foreign languages on the website but I cannot amend them. My concern is that the functionality for editing the content in Tiny MCE is not working for some reason or possibly for a nother reason.

Its not possible for me to switch off all of the other plugins to see if one of them is cancelling out the custom sidebars plugin on the live environment as this is a FTSE 150 website which cannot be unavailable.

Is there any other way to find out what is causing the issue?

Many thanks for you help

Regards

Gerard

---

this is what the console tells me:

JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed, version 1.4.1
widgets.php:205 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property ‘init’ of undefined
at widgets.php:205
widgets.php:209 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property ‘modelConstructors’ of undefined
at widgets.php:209
widgets.php:217 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property ‘modelConstructors’ of undefined
at widgets.php:217
widgets.php:225 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property ‘modelConstructors’ of undefined
at widgets.php:225
widgets.php:233 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property ‘modelConstructors’ of undefined
at widgets.php:233
widgets.php:247 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property ‘idBases’ of undefined
at widgets.php:247
widgets.php:253 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property ‘defaultSettings’ of undefined
at widgets.php:253
widgets.php:261 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property ‘idBases’ of undefined
at widgets.php:261
widgets.php:87210 Uncaught ReferenceError: acf is not defined
at widgets.php:87210
widgets.php:87217 Uncaught ReferenceError: acf is not defined
at widgets.php:87217
at widgets.php:87271
widgets.php:87274 Uncaught ReferenceError: acf is not defined
at widgets.php:87274
widgets.php:87304 Uncaught ReferenceError: wpWidgets is not defined
at widgets.php:87304
widgets.php:87310 Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
widgets.php:87430 Uncaught ReferenceError: tinymce is not defined
at widgets.php:87430
wp-langs-en.js?ver=4940-20190515:235 Uncaught ReferenceError: tinyMCE is not defined
at wp-langs-en.js?ver=4940-20190515:235
at wp-langs-en.js?ver=4940-20190515:519
widgets.php:87499 Uncaught ReferenceError: tinymce is not defined
at Object.load_ext (widgets.php:87499)
at widgets.php:87504
acf-input.min.js?ver=5.8.3:4 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property ‘autop’ of undefined
at acf.Model.onReady (acf-input.min.js?ver=5.8.3:4)
at u (acf-input.min.js?ver=5.8.3:1)
at Object.i (acf-input.min.js?ver=5.8.3:1)
at Object.i.doAction (acf-input.min.js?ver=5.8.3:1)
at HTMLDocument. (acf-input.min.js?ver=5.8.3:1)
at i (load-scripts.php?c=0…pointer&ver=5.2.3:2)
at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (load-scripts.php?c=0…pointer&ver=5.2.3:2)
at Function.ready (load-scripts.php?c=0…pointer&ver=5.2.3:2)
at HTMLDocument.J (load-scripts.php?c=0…pointer&ver=5.2.3:2)
wp-auth-check.min.js?ver=5.2.3:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property ‘hasClass’ of undefined
at HTMLDocument. (wp-auth-check.min.js?ver=5.2.3:1)
at HTMLDocument.dispatch (load-scripts.php?c=0…pointer&ver=5.2.3:3)
at HTMLDocument.r.handle (load-scripts.php?c=0…pointer&ver=5.2.3:3)
at Object.trigger (load-scripts.php?c=0…pointer&ver=5.2.3:3)
at Object.a.event.trigger (load-scripts.php?c=0…pointer&ver=5.2.3:8)
at HTMLDocument. (load-scripts.php?c=0…pointer&ver=5.2.3:3)
at Function.each (load-scripts.php?c=0…pointer&ver=5.2.3:2)
at a.fn.init.each (load-scripts.php?c=0…pointer&ver=5.2.3:2)
at a.fn.init.trigger (load-scripts.php?c=0…pointer&ver=5.2.3:3)
at Object. (heartbeat.min.js?ver=5.2.3:1)
wp-auth-check.min.js?ver=5.2.3:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property ‘hasClass’ of undefined
at HTMLDocument. (wp-auth-check.min.js?ver=5.2.3:1)
at HTMLDocument.dispatch (load-scripts.php?c=0…pointer&ver=5.2.3:3)
at HTMLDocument.r.handle (load-scripts.php?c=0…pointer&ver=5.2.3:3)
at Object.trigger (load-scripts.php?c=0…pointer&ver=5.2.3:3)
at Object.a.event.trigger (load-scripts.php?c=0…pointer&ver=5.2.3:8)
at HTMLDocument. (load-scripts.php?c=0…pointer&ver=5.2.3:3)
at Function.each (load-scripts.php?c=0…pointer&ver=5.2.3:2)
at a.fn.init.each (load-scripts.php?c=0…pointer&ver=5.2.3:2)
at a.fn.init.trigger (load-scripts.php?c=0…pointer&ver=5.2.3:3)
at Object. (heartbeat.min.js?ver=5.2.3:1)
wp-auth-check.min.js?ver=5.2.3:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property ‘hasClass’ of undefined
at HTMLDocument. (wp-auth-check.min.js?ver=5.2.3:1)
at HTMLDocument.dispatch (load-scripts.php?c=0…pointer&ver=5.2.3:3)
at HTMLDocument.r.handle (load-scripts.php?c=0…pointer&ver=5.2.3:3)
at Object.trigger (load-scripts.php?c=0…pointer&ver=5.2.3:3)
at Object.a.event.trigger (load-scripts.php?c=0…pointer&ver=5.2.3:8)
at HTMLDocument. (load-scripts.php?c=0…pointer&ver=5.2.3:3)
at Function.each (load-scripts.php?c=0…pointer&ver=5.2.3:2)
at a.fn.init.each (load-scripts.php?c=0…pointer&ver=5.2.3:2)
at a.fn.init.trigger (load-scripts.php?c=0…pointer&ver=5.2.3:3)
at Object. (heartbeat.min.js?ver=5.2.3:1)
wp-auth-check.min.js?ver=5.2.3:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property ‘hasClass’ of undefined
at HTMLDocument. (wp-auth-check.min.js?ver=5.2.3:1)
at HTMLDocument.dispatch (load-scripts.php?c=0…pointer&ver=5.2.3:3)
at HTMLDocument.r.handle (load-scripts.php?c=0…pointer&ver=5.2.3:3)
at Object.trigger (load-scripts.php?c=0…pointer&ver=5.2.3:3)
at Object.a.event.trigger (load-scripts.php?c=0…pointer&ver=5.2.3:8)
at HTMLDocument. (load-scripts.php?c=0…pointer&ver=5.2.3:3)
at Function.each (load-scripts.php?c=0…pointer&ver=5.2.3:2)
at a.fn.init.each (load-scripts.php?c=0…pointer&ver=5.2.3:2)
at a.fn.init.trigger (load-scripts.php?c=0…pointer&ver=5.2.3:3)
at Object. (heartbeat.min.js?ver=5.2.3:1)
wp-auth-check.min.js?ver=5.2.3:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property ‘hasClass’ of undefined
at HTMLDocument. (wp-auth-check.min.js?ver=5.2.3:1)
at HTMLDocument.dispatch (load-scripts.php?c=0…pointer&ver=5.2.3:3)
at HTMLDocument.r.handle (load-scripts.php?c=0…pointer&ver=5.2.3:3)
at Object.trigger (load-scripts.php?c=0…pointer&ver=5.2.3:3)
at Object.a.event.trigger (load-scripts.php?c=0…pointer&ver=5.2.3:8)
at HTMLDocument. (load-scripts.php?c=0…pointer&ver=5.2.3:3)
at Function.each (load-scripts.php?c=0…pointer&ver=5.2.3:2)
at a.fn.init.each (load-scripts.php?c=0…pointer&ver=5.2.3:2)
at a.fn.init.trigger (load-scripts.php?c=0…pointer&ver=5.2.3:3)
at Object. (heartbeat.min.js?ver=5.2.3:1)
wp-auth-check.min.js?ver=5.2.3:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property ‘hasClass’ of undefined
at HTMLDocument. (wp-auth-check.min.js?ver=5.2.3:1)
at HTMLDocument.dispatch (load-scripts.php?c=0…pointer&ver=5.2.3:3)
at HTMLDocument.r.handle (load-scripts.php?c=0…pointer&ver=5.2.3:3)
at Object.trigger (load-scripts.php?c=0…pointer&ver=5.2.3:3)
at Object.a.event.trigger (load-scripts.php?c=0…pointer&ver=5.2.3:8)
at HTMLDocument. (load-scripts.php?c=0…pointer&ver=5.2.3:3)
at Function.each (load-scripts.php?c=0…pointer&ver=5.2.3:2)
at a.fn.init.each (load-scripts.php?c=0…pointer&ver=5.2.3:2)
at a.fn.init.trigger (load-scripts.php?c=0…pointer&ver=5.2.3:3)
at Object. (heartbeat.min.js?ver=5.2.3:1)
wp-auth-check.min.js?ver=5.2.3:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property ‘hasClass’ of undefined
at HTMLDocument. (wp-auth-check.min.js?ver=5.2.3:1)
at HTMLDocument.dispatch (load-scripts.php?c=0…pointer&ver=5.2.3:3)
at HTMLDocument.r.handle (load-scripts.php?c=0…pointer&ver=5.2.3:3)
at Object.trigger (load-scripts.php?c=0…pointer&ver=5.2.3:3)
at Object.a.event.trigger (load-scripts.php?c=0…pointer&ver=5.2.3:8)
at HTMLDocument. (load-scripts.php?c=0…pointer&ver=5.2.3:3)
at Function.each (load-scripts.php?c=0…pointer&ver=5.2.3:2)
at a.fn.init.each (load-scripts.php?c=0…pointer&ver=5.2.3:2)
at a.fn.init.trigger (load-scripts.php?c=0…pointer&ver=5.2.3:3)
at Object. (heartbeat.min.js?ver=5.2.3:1)
wp-auth-check.min.js?ver=5.2.3:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property ‘hasClass’ of undefined
at HTMLDocument. (wp-auth-check.min.js?ver=5.2.3:1)
at HTMLDocument.dispatch (load-scripts.php?c=0…pointer&ver=5.2.3:3)
at HTMLDocument.r.handle (load-scripts.php?c=0…pointer&ver=5.2.3:3)
at Object.trigger (load-scripts.php?c=0…pointer&ver=5.2.3:3)
at Object.a.event.trigger (load-scripts.php?c=0…pointer&ver=5.2.3:8)
at HTMLDocument. (load-scripts.php?c=0…pointer&ver=5.2.3:3)
at Function.each (load-scripts.php?c=0…pointer&ver=5.2.3:2)
at a.fn.init.each (load-scripts.php?c=0…pointer&ver=5.2.3:2)
at a.fn.init.trigger (load-scripts.php?c=0…pointer&ver=5.2.3:3)
at Object. (heartbeat.min.js?ver=5.2.3:1)
wp-auth-check.min.js?ver=5.2.3:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property ‘hasClass’ of undefined
at HTMLDocument. (wp-auth-check.min.js?ver=5.2.3:1)
at HTMLDocument.dispatch (load-scripts.php?c=0…pointer&ver=5.2.3:3)
at HTMLDocument.r.handle (load-scripts.php?c=0…pointer&ver=5.2.3:3)
at Object.trigger (load-scripts.php?c=0…pointer&ver=5.2.3:3)
at Object.a.event.trigger (load-scripts.php?c=0…pointer&ver=5.2.3:8)
at HTMLDocument. (load-scripts.php?c=0…pointer&ver=5.2.3:3)
at Function.each (load-scripts.php?c=0…pointer&ver=5.2.3:2)
at a.fn.init.each (load-scripts.php?c=0…pointer&ver=5.2.3:2)
at a.fn.init.trigger (load-scripts.php?c=0…pointer&ver=5.2.3:3)
at Object. (heartbeat.min.js?ver=5.2.3:1)
wp-auth-check.min.js?ver=5.2.3:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property ‘hasClass’ of undefined
at HTMLDocument. (wp-auth-check.min.js?ver=5.2.3:1)
at HTMLDocument.dispatch (load-scripts.php?c=0…pointer&ver=5.2.3:3)
at HTMLDocument.r.handle (load-scripts.php?c=0…pointer&ver=5.2.3:3)
at Object.trigger (load-scripts.php?c=0…pointer&ver=5.2.3:3)
at Object.a.event.trigger (load-scripts.php?c=0…pointer&ver=5.2.3:8)
at HTMLDocument. (load-scripts.php?c=0…pointer&ver=5.2.3:3)
at Function.each (load-scripts.php?c=0…pointer&ver=5.2.3:2)
at a.fn.init.each (load-scripts.php?c=0…pointer&ver=5.2.3:2)
at a.fn.init.trigger (load-scripts.php?c=0…pointer&ver=5.2.3:3)
at Object. (heartbeat.min.js?ver=5.2.3:1)
wp-auth-check.min.js?ver=5.2.3:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property ‘hasClass’ of undefined
at HTMLDocument. (wp-auth-check.min.js?ver=5.2.3:1)
at HTMLDocument.dispatch (load-scripts.php?c=0…pointer&ver=5.2.3:3)
at HTMLDocument.r.handle (load-scripts.php?c=0…pointer&ver=5.2.3:3)
at Object.trigger (load-scripts.php?c=0…pointer&ver=5.2.3:3)
at Object.a.event.trigger (load-scripts.php?c=0…pointer&ver=5.2.3:8)
at HTMLDocument. (load-scripts.php?c=0…pointer&ver=5.2.3:3)
at Function.each (load-scripts.php?c=0…pointer&ver=5.2.3:2)
at a.fn.init.each (load-scripts.php?c=0…pointer&ver=5.2.3:2)
at a.fn.init.trigger (load-scripts.php?c=0…pointer&ver=5.2.3:3)
at Object. (heartbeat.min.js?ver=5.2.3:1)
wp-auth-check.min.js?ver=5.2.3:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property ‘hasClass’ of undefined
at HTMLDocument. (wp-auth-check.min.js?ver=5.2.3:1)
at HTMLDocument.dispatch (load-scripts.php?c=0…pointer&ver=5.2.3:3)
at HTMLDocument.r.handle (load-scripts.php?c=0…pointer&ver=5.2.3:3)
at Object.trigger (load-scripts.php?c=0…pointer&ver=5.2.3:3)
at Object.a.event.trigger (load-scripts.php?c=0…pointer&ver=5.2.3:8)
at HTMLDocument. (load-scripts.php?c=0…pointer&ver=5.2.3:3)
at Function.each (load-scripts.php?c=0…pointer&ver=5.2.3:2)
at a.fn.init.each (load-scripts.php?c=0…pointer&ver=5.2.3:2)
at a.fn.init.trigger (load-scripts.php?c=0…pointer&ver=5.2.3:3)
at Object. (heartbeat.min.js?ver=5.2.3:1)
wp-auth-check.min.js?ver=5.2.3:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property ‘hasClass’ of undefined
at HTMLDocument. (wp-auth-check.min.js?ver=5.2.3:1)
at HTMLDocument.dispatch (load-scripts.php?c=0…pointer&ver=5.2.3:3)
at HTMLDocument.r.handle (load-scripts.php?c=0…pointer&ver=5.2.3:3)
at Object.trigger (load-scripts.php?c=0…pointer&ver=5.2.3:3)
at Object.a.event.trigger (load-scripts.php?c=0…pointer&ver=5.2.3:8)
at HTMLDocument. (load-scripts.php?c=0…pointer&ver=5.2.3:3)
at Function.each (load-scripts.php?c=0…pointer&ver=5.2.3:2)
at a.fn.init.each (load-scripts.php?c=0…pointer&ver=5.2.3:2)
at a.fn.init.trigger (load-scripts.php?c=0…pointer&ver=5.2.3:3)
at Object. (heartbeat.min.js?ver=5.2.3:1)
wp-auth-check.min.js?ver=5.2.3:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property ‘hasClass’ of undefined
at HTMLDocument. (wp-auth-check.min.js?ver=5.2.3:1)
at HTMLDocument.dispatch (load-scripts.php?c=0…pointer&ver=5.2.3:3)
at HTMLDocument.r.handle (load-scripts.php?c=0…pointer&ver=5.2.3:3)
at Object.trigger (load-scripts.php?c=0…pointer&ver=5.2.3:3)
at Object.a.event.trigger (load-scripts.php?c=0…pointer&ver=5.2.3:8)
at HTMLDocument. (load-scripts.php?c=0…pointer&ver=5.2.3:3)
at Function.each (load-scripts.php?c=0…pointer&ver=5.2.3:2)
at a.fn.init.each (load-scripts.php?c=0…pointer&ver=5.2.3:2)
at a.fn.init.trigger (load-scripts.php?c=0…pointer&ver=5.2.3:3)
at Object. (heartbeat.min.js?ver=5.2.3:1)
wp-auth-check.min.js?ver=5.2.3:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property ‘hasClass’ of undefined
at HTMLDocument. (wp-auth-check.min.js?ver=5.2.3:1)
at HTMLDocument.dispatch (load-scripts.php?c=0…pointer&ver=5.2.3:3)
at HTMLDocument.r.handle (load-scripts.php?c=0…pointer&ver=5.2.3:3)
at Object.trigger (load-scripts.php?c=0…pointer&ver=5.2.3:3)
at Object.a.event.trigger (load-scripts.php?c=0…pointer&ver=5.2.3:8)
at HTMLDocument. (load-scripts.php?c=0…pointer&ver=5.2.3:3)
at Function.each (load-scripts.php?c=0…pointer&ver=5.2.3:2)
at a.fn.init.each (load-scripts.php?c=0…pointer&ver=5.2.3:2)
at a.fn.init.trigger (load-scripts.php?c=0…pointer&ver=5.2.3:3)
at Object. (heartbeat.min.js?ver=5.2.3:1)

Answer (score 0):

Not trying to be rude, but this is a clear case for having regular backups and why updates should not be run on a live site without testing.

There are too many variables for us to help troubleshoot errors.  It could be that you updated PHP, or your server was updated.  Not just the Wordpress core, plugins or theme.

You are going to need to pull a copy of this site onto a development platform and test for conflicts while completing the update process.

1. Make a backup (or use one if you have been taking regular backups)
2. Create a development platform.
3. Install the backup.
4. Find the conflict / problem by disabling other plugins. (hopefully it's not the theme).
5. Check for compatibility with your server (php, etc)
6. If that doesn't work find a new widget plugin.